# How to animate a button to show a view to right and bounce to back when it is tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiviewanimation

I want a button to expand the view to right when the button is tapped and bounce back when the view is tapped? can anyone suggest me?
[Here is the screen shot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFrth.png)

Comment: you need to make a custom control using UIView or UIControl. please research about them and make something on your own. If you got stuck, post your question with some code and analytics. You might get help.

Comment: Add 1 UIButton with SOS title and add 1 UIView(or button with title) with UILabel under SOS button. Change width of UIView(or button) when SOS button tapped. you can use UIView.animate() for animation, bounce, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Create a view that is the same size as the button behind the button, set the width of the view based on the right constraint and use the animation in the click response of the button, which should achieve the effect you want;

Answer (score 0):

i think that you should use CoreGraphics, there is many simple tutorials you can find on youtube
Example

```
button.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0, y: 0)
```

this method is what you are looking for in order to extend your custom view/button

Answer (score 0):

Example like this: hope it helps.

```
let contraint:CGFloat = 0.0
if backViewWidthContraint.constant == 0 {
            contraint = 300.0
        }else{
            contraint = 0.0
        }


    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3) {
                    self.backViewWidthContraint.constant = contraint
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```